# How do I break line at the range on ReportLab?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to write text on a PDF file but if the line is bigger than the page size it overflows and doesn't automatically go to the next line. How do I provide a range when the line overflows and automatically break the text to the next line?

Note: The text is automatically generated and may always not overflow.

Current Output:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Code:

```
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4, bottomup=0)
can.setFont('RobotoBold', 11)
can.drawString(40, 658, 'In Word:')
can.setFont('Roboto', 11)
can.drawString(84, 658, final_string)
```

Comment: `canvas.Canvas.drawString` is useful sometimes, but don't over-rely on it. You need to use a `flowable`. RTFM - page 65 is a good place to start. https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can break `final_string` into chunks by using list comprehension as follows.

```py
n = 80 # or whatever length you find suitable.
finals_string_chunks = [final_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(final_string), n)]
```

And then call `can.drawString()` within a for-each loop for each string in the list `finals_string_chunks`.

You might have to do some math for updating appropriate x, y coordinates on your `drawString` method as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, in your approach, there is a possibility of breaking the words in between as the loop is breaking based on length. For example a word can be broken like Hund <linebreak> red